# Compactness and Lebesgue Number proof

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

Let $X$ be a compact metric space. Then, every open cover of $X$ has a lebesgue number.

Suppose $X$ has an open cover $(U_i)_{i\in I}$, which admits no lebesgue number. In particular, for each $n$, there exists a sequence of non-empty sets, $A_n$, for which, $A_n$ is not contained in any of the $U_i$.Considering AOC, we choose $x_n\in A_n\backslash U_i$. Then, $x_n$ has a convergent subsequence, $(x_{n_k})$ such that $x_{n_k}\rightarrow x$ for some $x\in U_m$. Since $x_{n_k}$ converges, there must exists $K$, for which, $k\geq K$ implies $x_{n_k}\in U_m$. Contradiction.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof has a logical error in the second sentence. The statement

> ... there exists a sequence of non-empty sets $A_n$ for which $A_n$ is not contained in any of the $U_i$...

does not imply what follows. That statement is not quite what you want. Instead, what you want is this:

> ... there exists a sequence of non-empty sets $A_n$ for which $A_n$ is not contained in any of the $U_i$ *and* such that the diamater of $A_n$ approaches $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Also, your final contradiction is not a contradiction: there is nothing contradictory about the implication

> ... $k \ge K$ implies $x_{n_k} \in U_m$.

The contradiction you want is

> ... $k \ge K$ implies $A_{n_k} \subset U_m$.

The last thing I'll say is: nowhere in your proof have you used the metric in any substantial way. That's a big clue that there are some ideas missing.

Comment: Doesn't "... there exists a sequence of non-empty sets  for which  is not contained in any of the  and such that the diamater of  approaches 0 as →∞." imply what I wrote?  ( Because that's what I had in mind) Also, the contradiction was that $x_{n_k}$ cannot be in $U_m$ because $x_{n_k}$ was chosen to not be in $U_m$. Why isn't that a contradiction?

Comment: Your right about the first question, I edited. As for your your second sentence, although you said "we choose $x_n \in A_n \setminus U_i$", this does not make any sense because you have not specified any particular $U_i$.

Comment: Nonetheless, regarding your first question, you *still* need the stronger implication, including that the diameter of $A_n$ converges to zero, in the portions of the proof that follow.

Comment: I understand. Thank you so much for your time.